# Objective C Calling Method on Another Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, methods, uiwebview

I have 2 classes, `MainViewController` and 'FooView' for example.

In MainViewController I have a method called `-(void)doSearch`

I'm trying to call `doSearch` from Foo, is see in the log "doSearch" (NSLog) but the UIWebView doesn't response.

**Foo**

```
MainViewController *mainVc = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
[mainVc doSearch];
```

**MainViewController**

```
- (void)doSearch {
    NSLog(@"doSearch");
    [myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]]];
}
```

myWebView is a UIWebView.

Thanks,

Guy Dor

Comment: What do you mean by "no success"? Any errors/warnings?

Comment: Have a look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868511/reaching-a-function-in-a-different-class

Comment: You are not using the correct objects i suppose. Post how you create the views and how you access the objects.

Comment: Non of them is null, I tried initWithNibName and still no response from the UIWebView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something is nil here.  In Obj-C you can send messages (call methods) on a nil object without an error or exception.  In your case, your MainViewController could be null in the FooView, or it is possible that something in that method is nil.  For example, if have a xib file for that view controller, then it needs to be loaded with initWithNibName:bundle:.  If you don't do that, then the IBOutlets will be nil (possibly the myWebView in your doSearch: method for example).

Answer (score 0):

Check if "mainVc" is not nil. You are probably falling at initializing it.

Comment: Try this: MainViewController *mainVc = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];

Answer (score 0):

if u create MainViewController with NIB file then u have to call like this.

```
  MainViewController *mainVc = [[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];

  [mainVc doSearch];
```

Comment: Thanks but if I init a MainViewController with initWithNibName I actually recreate my entire interface because under this method I add some views to the xib file